# Sql Advantage Error : Open Client is not configured correctly

Tags: sybase

I am trying to run the Sql Advantage editor but getting below mentioned error.

[image: Error :]

```
Internal failure while initializing the SQL Advantage.
Please check that Open Client is configured correctly.
```

Please check the SET command output in the attached screenshot.Also, I can see two folders in my system for OCS-12_5 and OCS-15_0. This may be causing this problem. I also tried to run a bat file with these commands but getting same error:

Bat file commands:

```
set SYBASE= C:\Sybase\OCS-12_5
set SYBASE_OCS=OCS-12_5
C:\Sybase\OCS-12_5\sqladv-12_5\sqladv.exe
```

Please suggest.

[image: SET Command Output]

Answer (score 0):

SQL Advantage is no longer supported with ASE 15.x
But you can probably still run it if you set your environment to 12.5 (it works for me). Put all the environment settings in a .bat file, and then (in the .bat file) kick off sqladv.exe.

Comment: Could you please let me know what settings should I put there ? I tried with the above settings in the bat file but it didn't work for me.

Comment: there should be a SYBASE.bat file in your 12.5 directory. This should contains the settings you need.